# How to reach a specific position of a buffered media in QMediaPlayer?

Tags: c++, qt

I am currently trying things with the player example (`Qt\Examples\Qt-5.6\qtmultimedia\multimediawidgets\player`) of Qt. But I can't manage to reach a specific position of any video I am playing, even when the `QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus` is `BufferedMedia`.

In order to do this, I just created a `QLineEdit` where the user puts the time in seconds where he wants to go in the video, and a `QPushButton` which emits a signal `toThisPosition(int)`.

```
void Player::GoButtonClicked()
{
    qint64 pos = m_LineEdit->text().toInt() * 1000; // time in seconds
    emit thisPosition(pos); // signal emitted
}
```

I reach the slot `void Player::positionChanged(qint64 progress)` of the player, with the good time in seconds, but here are the problems :

- The video stays at the time it was before clicking, **even if the cursor goes to the time asked**
  ;
- I go two times in my slot: one with the good time, one with the time before. For example if the video was at 10 seconds, and I ask 30, it goes to 30 then goes back to 10 and some (like if the video played and ignored my signal).

**Is it even possible to do that? Is `QMediaPlayer`that limited?**